# Trouble Importing Resources with Eclipse

Tags: java, image, resources, jpeg

I'm setting a JLabel to show an icon.

```
        public Icon getIcon(String type) throws IOException
    {

    String avatar = "Academic.jpg";
    switch(type)
    {
    case"Academic": avatar ="Academic.jpg"; break;
    case"Alchemist": avatar ="Alchemist.jpg"; break;
    case"Assassin": avatar ="Assassin.jpg"; break;
}
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(avatar);
    Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(logo);
    return icon;
}
```

"input" is still null on the 3rd line, when "avatar" contains a string "Pic.jpg". 
My resources folder is in the src folder? Have I done something wrong? How does eclipse know how to find the images?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't.  The JRE looks whereever you are telling it.  You did not even include the code that populates input.  So no real way to address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are just passing the file name with no path of any kind so unless that file is located at the root of your project, and or classpath it will not be found.  You will need to add the path details of where the file is located.  Which sounds like it will at least start with:

/src/resources//Academic.jpg

Comment: I added this image to the root then tried again. i'm still getting:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at ArmouryCharacterLists.getIcon(ArmouryCharacterLists.java:654)
 at MainFrame$2.valueChanged(MainFrame.java:99)

Comment: Then apparently the root is not where the class loader is being started from.  I would try classLoader.getResource("/").getPath() to a log or System.out.println() so you can see where the path is relative from.

Comment: That was not supposed to fix the problem.  It was supposed to show you the path the classloader is starting from so you can figured out what relative path you need to add to point it to so it can see the file.